# How we can 1 MONTH in a DateType variable in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to add 1 Month in `v_TempEffectiveDate`. What will be the correct statement?

```
  WHILE v_TempEffectiveDate <= v_EndDate LOOP
           v_TempEffectiveDate := ADD_MONTHS('v_TempEffectiveDate' + 1); --v_TempEffectiveDate + 1 MONTH
           v_MonthsElapsed := v_MonthsElapsed + 1;
        END LOOP; --WHILE v_TempEffectiveDate <= v_EndDate 
        v_MonthsElapsed := v_MonthsElapsed - 1;
```

I got the following error:

> PL/SQL : statement is ignored PLS-00306: worng number or type of argument in call to "ADD_Months()

Comment: PL/SQL : statement is ignored
PLS-00306: worng number or type of argument in call to "ADD_Months()

Comment: Have you tried `ADD_MONTH(v_TempEffectiveDate,1)`? without single quotes.

Comment: i have used the same stmt above then i am getting PLS-00306: worng number type of argument in call "ADD_MONTHS" I have tried @JSapkota

Comment: As JSapkota says: the variable shouldn't be in quotes, and you shouldn't have + 1 in the argument; the function takes two arguments, separated by comma, and the second argument is 1.

Comment: @mathguy i have removed then i am getting PLS-00306 worng number type of argument in call 'ADD_MONTHS'

Comment: And did you remove the + sign, and replace it with comma:  `,`  ??

Comment: Post your updated code block.

Comment: Thnk Guys its a silly mistake got it thanks a lot